# custumor view with java swing and OPL studio

Tags: java, cplex, opl

I work with CPLEX in OPL studio, and I want to display the result (custumoe view) on an interface made with java swing, my problem is that I don't have idea how to do this, there was API that allows to do that? or any thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes there are APIs to call OPL from java.
You have many examples in
CPLEX_Studio1261\opl\examples\opl_interfaces\java

regards